# How to show updated values using BindingSource (Changes from another windows form or workstation)

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview, bindingsource

how to refresh data of a bindingsource / display updated values from another form other than clearing and refilling the datatable? or setting the datasource first to null is the only solution? Here's my code for refresh button:

```
Private Sub btnRefresh_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRefresh.Click
    Try
        Me.bsTransactionHeader.EndEdit()
        Me.bsMachine.EndEdit()

        Me.myDataset.GetChanges()
        Me.adpTransactionHeader.Update(Me.myDataset.MntTransactionHeader)
        Me.adpTransactionDetail.Update(Me.myDataset.MntTransactionDetail)
        Me.adpTransactionMachinePart.Update(Me.myDataset.MntTransactionMachinePart)
        Me.adpTransactionSparePart.Update(Me.myDataset.MntTransactionSparePart)
        Me.adpTransactionUser.Update(Me.myDataset.MntTransactionUser)
        Me.adpMachine.Update(Me.myDataset.MntMachine)
        Me.myDataset.AcceptChanges()

        dgvTransactionHeader.Refresh()

        Me.bsMachine.ResetBindings(False)
        Me.bsTransactionHeader.ResetBindings(False)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, method.SetExcpTitle(ex), MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

If the user clicked Return button, it should appear immediately to another form as ongoing transaction. Thank you.
[Machine Monitoring System](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNR8v.jpg)

Comment: This type of thing you're going to want to implement some sort of messaging system.  you will need something to broadcast to apps on other machines the update request, then something listing for that update request, have a look at TCPListener.

Comment: Alternatively, you could have a flag/indicator somewhere, maybe in your db that your app polls at set intervals to indicate refresh is required

Comment: I already have a workaround for this, I recall the fill function of all adapters involve since its 'clear before fill' property is default to true. But before that, I stored the current position and scroll index then re-set it after that. I will try to implement tcplistener or signalr. Thanks.